# Can we use eval function to get user created lists?

Tags: python

I tried to use the 
**eval** function to get user created lists but it just shows an error saying "str object is not callable".

```
L1=eval(input("Enter list :"))
L2=eval(input("Enter list :"))
L=L1+L2
print(L3)
```

It's a simple code, but major problem. When I used the same code on my friend's computer, it worked just fine, no matter how many times I executed the program. But, in my case...

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-160888e6af35> in <module>
----> 1 L1=eval(input("Enter list :"))
      2 L2=eval(input("Enter list :"))
      3 L=L1+L2
      4 print(L3)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

it just shows this error, not even executing for a single time. Is it because of the version or am I just being stupid?

I know how else to run the program,

```
L1=list(input("Enter list :"))
L2=list(input("Enter list :"))
L=L1+L2
print(L3)
```

using the **list** function. But I just want to know why the **eval** function worked before and not now.

Comment: You have defined `eval` as a variable holding some string value. In any case, you are not advised to use `eval`.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: The error indicates that either `input` or `eval` have overwritten with a string.

Comment: works for me. Except you have L= not L3=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, do del eval, and del input, and try again. You may have overwritten one of those python functions

```
In [496]: eval = 'what'                                                                                                                                                                        

In [497]: L2=eval(input("Enter list :")) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                      
Enter list :12
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-497-19ab867bbdee> in <module>
----> 1 L2=eval(input("Enter list :"))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

You can fix it by:

```
del eval
or
del input
```

depending on which python function you've overwritten. My guess is input, but try both. You can see i get the same error if i've overwritten those functions with a string